# How to check if "Restrict where this project can be run" is checked or not in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

When a job is building in Jenkins, how can I check if "Restrict where this project can be run" is checked or not without installing any plugin.

I thought it would show in environment variables but i didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins uses assignedNode property for restricting the project to label/node. 
You can get this property using

1. /config.xml - Look for assignedNode property
2. Using groovy (run this from master console)

   def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('')

   println job.getAssignedLabel().getExpression()

For more information, check - [getAssignedLabel](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#getAssignedLabel())

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The groovy script doesn't give correct results for pipeline scripts, however, if the script uses the `agent { 'xy' }` - directive. The groovy will always show `master` - and for the initial pipeline script, that is of course always true. Something to keep in mind.